# How can I test a specific screen in my app without navigating all hierarchy until there

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, testing

Say you are developing Settings.app (the iPhone settings app) and you want to add features in the Text Replacement system.

To test that screen one must go through all the screens `Settings > General > Keyboard > Text replacement` which is very painful if you do it often.

What are the options to directly test the Text Replacement screen? Or, alternatively, to go the specific screen quickly?

Have in mind that usually we set things up on the previous screens: state, singletons, global variables, etc…

I know there's no magic way to do it. What I'd like to know then is what are your tricks and advices (you use different schemes? you organize your state code in a way that's easier to test the screen?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use storyboards **initialViewController** checkbox for this purpose. In Storyboard -> ViewController check for property called initialViewController. By enabling this you will directly navigate to that specific screen. Please ignore, if this is not your requirement.

Comment: That doesn't help since we usually set state navigating through the previous screens

Comment: In your appDelegate, set that view controller as rootViewController

Answer (score 0):

If you dont make that screen apart from other code, it will be really hard, move all the setup from the previous screen to app delegate and set that screen as rootViewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I usually add a test button that I can hide later in production. You can set it up to skip login but also could include an other code you want in there or go straight to the view you want. I have the button to different functions that can change so that I don't have to add and remove anything else afterwards, just hide the button again or redirect to a new function. You might have to mock some data in your case but if you are just checking the UI as you build it then this is a good quick test method.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using storyboard Select Viewcontroller which you want to test and in storyboard check **initialViewController** checkbox for this purpose,
so it will launch as your first screen so without navigating to all other screen you can check checkbox of **initialViewController**.

[image]